# $centerSphere is not returning any geojson polygons (mongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, polygon, geojson, point

I am having a lot of trouble with the following Mongo query

```
location: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[lon,lat],radians] } }
```

It only returns geoJSON Points and ignores all my geoJSON Polygons for some reason. The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/) states:

> You can use the $centerSphere operator on both GeoJSON objects and legacy coordinate pairs.

I am using Mongoose to run the queries and my geoJSON is coverted from WellKnown Text by the NPM module [wellknown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wellknown). This is how my geoJSON looks after the wellknown module has converted them:

```
 "location": {
    "coordinates": [
        22.1,
        33.3
    ],
    "type": "Point"
}
```

and

```
"location": {
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                43,
                30
            ],
            [
                40,
                28
            ],
            [
                49,
                27
            ],
            [
                43,
                30
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                44,
                28
            ],
            [
                44.7,
                28.8
            ],
            [
                46,
                28
            ],
            [
                44,
                28
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "type": "Polygon"
}
```

My Mongoose schema is defined as:

```
location: {
  type: schema.Types.Mixed,
  index: '2dsphere',
  required: false
}
```

I should add that the withinPolygon methods work as expected and I get both the Points and Polygons returned. The following works completely fine:

```
location: { $geoWithin: { $geometry: geoJSON } }
```

Thank you for any help. I have read the documentation and can't see anywhere where it mentions that the $centerSphere only returns geoJSON Points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the recent release of MongoDB version 3.6.0-rc0, you can now query GeoJSON LineStrings and Polygons with [$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) geospatial operator [$centerSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/).

See also [SERVER-27968](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27968) more information about the update.